# Перевод ResulSet в JTable посредством rs2xml.jar

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.
Тестовая программа "Время прихода-ухода сотрудников". Есть JComboBox который заполняется из БД(myaql). При нажатии на кнопку "Пришел" сотрудником, в БД добавляется время нажатия на эту кнопку и выводится в JTable. Проблема в том что, каждый новый сотрудник должен выводиться в новой строке, а сейчас он просто заменяется последующим запросом.

```
comeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String user = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            try {
           ResultSet rs = preparedStatement(String.format(query,user)).executeQuery();
                table.setModel(resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            pack();
        }
    });
```

Метод resultSetToTableModel() это метод библиотеки rs2xml.jar

Comment: Все, понял. Почему у вас в запросе указывается пользователь? У вас выводится время на 1 пользователя - все окей. Так что переписывайте свой запрос.

Comment: Если же вы хотите следующий функционал - в таблицу добавляется только тот пользователь, который выбран в выпадающем списке - вам следует создать метод добавления, так как resultSetToTableModel - создает модель. Заполняет и возвращает ссылку. Вам же нужно:  
1) Получить модель таблицы (getModel)
2) Привести ее к типу DefaultTableModel
3) Вызвать метод addRow() - добавление новой строки  
В принципе, зная, как реализован метод resultSetToTableModel, можно аналогично склепать метод, добавляющий к существующей модели строки из набора данных.

Comment: Для начала обратитесь к документации [How To Use Tables][1].  
И стоит изучить реализацию метода resultSetToTableModel - она может многое для вас прояснить [Technojeeves: ResultSet To TableModel][2]
[1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html  
[2]: http://technojeeves.com/index.php/9-freebies/22-resultset-to-tablemodel